# Flutter Await for websocket response

Tags: flutter, websocket

Solved
I've solved this problem using a Future function and using Completer inside the function.

I am getting some Images from my server with websockets.
I have a function that emits an event with the name of the image that I need and sends an event with the Image, that is working fine, but I need my App to wait for the return of my function because my app is calling the function and trying to go to the next page without the image.
Can someone explain to me how can I make my app wait for my function to return ?

Update

I am using Stream Builder now but I can't return the data from my function.

```
Stream<List> getFile(List imageL) async*{
  if(imageL.isNotEmpty){
     List downloadedData = List();
     socket.emit("PostsImagem", (imageL));
     socket.on("ImagemPost", (dados) {
         downloadedData = dados;
         imageL = List();
        });
 //I can't return the downloadedData because is inside the                     //socket.on()
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know much about flutter but for anyone to answer they'll need to see some of your code. Do check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: You should use async/await when you call the function and use "then" after the function to make sure that it will move to other page after you get the image.

Comment: Well I can get around the problem if I use stream builder and wile the data is empty stay on the loading screen, my problem now is that when I receive the Event from my server I can't return the data, I've updated the post with my code.